# Datepicker default date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using [datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) , and in my dropdown the default selected year is 1920 , if I select a date the input value will have `d/m/2020`. If I select from dropdown another year, will work correctly. The problem is only if I don't change the year. Also `setDate` is not working.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
    $('.wcfm_datepicker').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({
            setDate: "7/11/2009",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1920:2010",
        });
    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can set default Date . Please, Try this.

```
$('.wcfm_datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '7/11/2009');
```

Comment: I tried to use this along with the rest of the property, but no change. But that's not important for me, I was interested about the year bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution, it's not for every one, but for me it does the job. You have to add `maxDate`.

```
$(this).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-18",
    maxDate: '-18y',
});
```